# plot data at variable points using gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

Here is my data file

```
 seconds        data
 (x-axis       ( y axis
  points)      points)
3.880000,       20
3.920000,       10
3.960000,       20
4.000000,       20
4.080000,       20
4.120000,       20
4.570000,       20
4.620000,       10
4.650000,       10
4.690000,       10
4.750000,       20
 .
 .
 .
and so on
```

I want to plot points in column 2 at positions specified by column 1

ie I want 20 , 10 , 20 20, 20 etc to be present at 3.88 , 3.92, 3.96 on xaxis

Can anybody tell me how to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose your data is in 1.txt:

plot "1.txt" using 1:2

Answer (score 4):

I know it's been a long time, but for anyone else who stumbles upon this...
For this datafile, you'll also need a `set datafile separator ','`

e.g.

```
set datafile separator ','
plot 'data.dat' using 1:2
```

As a matter of style, it is probably best practice to explicitly comment out the header of the datafile using '#' characters.  e.g.

```
# seconds        data
# (x-axis       ( y axis
#  points)        points)
3.880000,       20
3.920000,       10
3.960000,       20
4.000000,       20
4.080000,       20
4.120000,       20
4.570000,       20
4.620000,       10
4.650000,       10
4.690000,       10
4.750000,       20
```

For this simple example, it works without the comments, but other, more complicated datafiles may not.